# UPPERCASE Constraint in SQL

Tags: mysql, constraint

What will be the query to add UPPERCASE Constraint to a column of pre-existing table? The question demands to ensure that the entries are in UPPERCASE.

Comment: What's your version of MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `CHECK` constraint to enforce that the column always contains uppercase values.

```
-- as new table
CREATE TABLE t1(c1 VARCHAR(200) CONSTRAINT c1_upper CHECK (BINARY UPPER(c1) = BINARY c1));
INSERT INTO t1(c1) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO t1(c1) VALUES ('A');
SELECT * FROM t1;

-- altering existing table
CREATE TABLE t2 (c2 VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE t2 ADD CONSTRAINT c2_upper CHECK (BINARY c2 = BINARY UPPER(c2));
INSERT INTO t2(c2) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO t2(c2) VALUES ('A');
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

SQL Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4d4e277ea6993d7b66a3b2f4871a320

Older versions of MySQL don't have check constraints. You can work around this by doing DML against a checked view. This works in version 5.5.

```
CREATE TABLE t1(c1 VARCHAR(200));
CREATE VIEW v1 AS SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE BINARY c1 = BINARY UPPER(c1) WITH CHECK OPTION;
INSERT INTO v1(c1) VALUES ('a');
-- fails
INSERT INTO v1(c1) VALUES ('A');
-- succeeds
```

SQL fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=7416cfbbbbbd1161d48785dd384d5d30

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL does not enforce this, instead it silently ignores it. Fiddle at:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a0a52b95c3dab531c80a1dbac5792aa

Comment: update fiddle with both variants: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e050f0edf55fa204b2a3d30179d1ac64

Comment: @Lennart updated fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=03ac9597eaf9914ef4d730d66c88f69a

Comment: Interesting, so if the keyword constraint is missing in the column level constraint it is ignored, but otherwise works as expected. What did you change in the table level constraint to make it work?

Comment: @Lennart changed `upper(binary(x))` to `binary(upper(x))` since we want to compare binary to binary

Comment: It doesn't need a constraint name. Your fiddle with minimal changes: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=da12d50e8388649a866667c03d4de737

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107766/discussion-between-durette-and-lennart).